# Cordova Android Will Not Display StatusBar

Tags: android, cordova, statusbar

I have an issue I have been trying to solve, none of the solutions online I have seen have helped either.

Very simple, so you think the solution would be as well.
On the Android platform for Cordova build I am using the StatusBar plugin which is set in the config.xml to preference and DISPLAY it...Yes, I am trying to get it to display in the app and not hide. It seems to be hidden every time the app runs.

In my InAppBrowser option string, I also set fullscreen=no so that that won't affect it either.

Running the app in the simulator and on-device both hide it still. Would someone possibly know a solution to FORCE the status bar to show and if not, what are the causes of this?

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    //InAppBrowser Init
    var options = "location=no,fullscreen=no,zoom=no"
    Browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.app.example', '_self', options);
```

The StatusBar plugin is also being imported correctly and can be seen here, this was done via plugman:

[image]

Here is my Config.xml file for better supporting information:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.pulse_co" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
<feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="OneSignalPush">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.OneSignalPush" />
</feature>

<name>Pulse</name>
<description>
    Add Pulse App Description Here
</description>
<author email="email@test.com" href="https://support.example.com">
    Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="https://root.domain.co*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.statusbar.StatusBar" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install statusbar plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

If that still doesn't work, try calling show after deviceready event

```
StatusBar.show();
```

Remove

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
```

Or set it to false

Also remove

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Or set it to false

OverlaysWebview males the statusbar transparent

Comment: I added more supporting information above. I do have the plugin installed and added StatucBar.show() and it had no effect.

Comment: Edited with some more posible solutions

Answer (score 2):

The options only have effect on `InAppBrowser` if you use `'_blank'`.

- `'_self'` = open in Cordova window
- `'_blank'` = open in InAppBrowser window
- `'_system'` = open in system browser

Comment: I actually tried that as well and no difference to the status bar

Comment: tried what? I just explained how the InAppBrowser plugin works. None of the options are to hide or show the status bar

Comment: I understand that I'm simply mentioning that I did use all of the browser window flags in InAppBrowser. I appreciate the tidbit of info but yet it doesn't address the issue at hand so I can't accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: can you add the preferences that you are using and make sure you have the plugin correctly installed? Because that's more relevant than what you provided

Comment: That's a very good point, thanks. I went ahead and updated it to hold the contents of my config.xml, a screenshot of the structure of the plugin to see that it's been imported. Hopefully, that helps more. Its been a while since I have used Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me

For anyone still facing this,
according to [Cordova plugin page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

> fullscreen: Sets whether the InappBrowser WebView is displayed
> fullscreen or not. In fullscreen mode, the status bar is hidden.
> Default value is **yes**.

So, in order to keep status bar visible, pass `fullscreen: "no"` in options

```
let browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(
      "https://github.com"
      "_target",
      { zoom: "no", location: "no", fullscreen: "no" }
);
```